# Show only text on spinner without dropdown

Tags: android, spinner, android-spinner

i want to show a image and text on spinner & dont want to see the dropdown, look at the image shown below,  like this need to have text and image. i.e image at left side and text at right end. Also we require selection happening on the spinner.

Eg: If i click on setDate the calender should come and chosen date should sit on spinner.

[image]

Comment: why you want use spinner? use one `textView` and `imageView` and in changing just change the `text` and `image`

Comment: yes, but i m trying to implement through spinner, is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

just add following line for disabling spinner:

```
        spinner.setClickable(false);
```

and for selecting your row you can use following code:

```
    spinner.setSelection(spinnerPosition);
```

that `spinnerPosition` is that position that you want.

Comment: @Shayanpourvatan, i just need to add spinner.setClickable(false); will it work?

Comment: what you want? you want select or disable selection?

Comment: i want selection, could you please paste your code. waiting desperately

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42694/discussion-between-shayan-pourvatan-and-lll)

Comment: i tried yest, and felt better to use custom view to implement the same, however the answer which u had posted at the beginning is the correct one though it will not give selection appearance.